# refresh a div using jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, refresh

I am using phongap and jquery mobile to build an application which should use JSON to list the recent posts in a wordpress blog and then allow you to click the article and then be taken to a page which shows you the full post. 
My code can list all the articles but the problem is that the code which is supposed to display the full article in a div is not working.
I have the following code:

---

```
<html>       
<link href="jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile-1.0a3.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="jquery-mobile/jquery-1.5.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile-1.0a3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="phonegap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
function onBodyLoad(){    
    document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false); }  

$(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://blog.smartapplications.co.zw/?json=get_recent_posts",
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(json_results){
            console.log(json_results);
            // Need to add UL on AJAX call or formatting of userlist is not displayed
            $('#blogList').append('<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="d" data-divider-theme="e" data-count-theme="b"></ul>');
            listItems = $('#blogList').find('ul');
            $.each(json_results.posts, function(key) {
                html = '<h3><a href="#post_id_'+json_results.posts[key].id+'">'+json_results.posts[key].title+'</a></h3>';


                listItems.append('<li>'+html+'</li>');
            });
            // Need to refresh list after AJAX call
            $('#blogList ul').listview();

            $.each(json_results.posts, function(key){
                    div_html='<div data-role="page" id="#post_id_'+json_results. posts[key].id+'"><div data-role="header"><h1>'+json_results. posts[key].title +'</h1></div><div data-role="content ">'+json_results. posts[key].text+'</div></div>';
                    $('#content_blog').html(div_html);
                    });

        }
    });
})

</script>

</head> 
<body onload = "onBodyLoad();"> 
<div data-role="page" id="page">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Home</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">   
        <ul data-role="listview">
            <li><a href="#page1">Latest Articles</a></li>
        </ul>       
    </div>

</div>

<div data-role="page" id="page1">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Latest Articles</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="blog_content" style="padding:0px;"> 
    <div id="blogList"></div>
    </div>  
</div>



<div id="content_blog" data-role="slider">  
</div>  
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: just a query..  why r u using jquery.mobile-1.0a3..
u should always use the latest

Answer (score 3):

try doing

```
$('#blogList ul').listview("refresh");
```

instead of

```
$('#blogList ul').listview();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong! here  :

```
  $('#blogList').append('<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="d" data-divider-theme="e" data-count-theme="b"></ul>');
```

you close  then you are adding

```
 listItems.append('<li>'+html+'</li>');
```

`<li>` should be inside of `<ul>` tag.